# Use Jquery variables to make different DIVs appear and disappear

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a webpage that has 4 divs on the splash page.  When the page first loads only the home div is visible, the other three are hidden.

There are buttons connected to jquery click events to make the current visible div "evaporate" and make the div that the user has selected "appear".

As of now every single button has its own entire jquery click event with the old div name to "evaporate" and the new div name to "appear" hard-coded directly into it.

This seems like needless repetition of code.

I want to have one single jquery click-event that simply accepts two string variables, one string variable that represents the old div to "evaporate" and one string variable that represents the new div to "appear" and then each html-button has the two string variables stored inside of it.

I don't know syntactically how to do this.

```
        <div id="homeDiv">HOME PAGE CONTENT</div>

        <div id="contactDiv">CONTACT CONTENT</div>

        <div id="resumeDiv">RESUME CONTENT</div>

        <div id="portfolioDiv">PORTFOLIO CONTENT</div>

<script>

     $('#contactButton').click(function() {

          $('#homePage').addClass('blur-out-expand-fwd');

          setTimeout(function() {

            $('#homePage').hide();
            $('#contactPage').show();
            $('#contactPage').addClass('focus-in-contract-bck');

          }, 500);

        });


        $('#contactHomeButton').click(function() {

          $('#contactPage').addClass('blur-out-expand-fwd');

          setTimeout(function() {

            $('#contactPage').hide();
            $('#homePage').show();
            $('#homePage').addClass('focus-in-contract-bck');

          }, 500);

        });

 </script>
```

Comment: Please stop inserting your website into the post. It is spam. You should provide a [mcve] and not need a remote link.

Comment: Is there more to your HTML that we can see? Some parent elements perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a solution:

Give all the buttons a class of "navButton" then attach that to the jquery click event, then each button element has an oldDiv attribute and a newDiv attribute that gets read by the click event, like this:

CONTACT

$('.navButton').click(function(){

```
 var oldDiv = "#" + $(this).attr("oldDiv");
 var newDiv = "#" + $(this).attr("newDiv");

$(oldDiv).addClass('blur-out-expand-fwd');
$(oldDiv).removeClass('focus-in-contract-bck');
$(newDiv).removeClass('blur-out-expand-fwd');
$(newDiv).removeClass('focus-in-contract-bck');

setTimeout(function(){

    $(oldDiv).hide();
    $(newDiv).show();
    $(newDiv).addClass('focus-in-contract-bck');

},500  );
```

});